# converting map to list through method reference in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have the below way of converting map to list through Java 8, but I want to use method reference instead of lambda, please advise how to convert the below program to make use of method reference functionality of Java 8

Below is my program

```
  Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(10, "apple");
  map.put(20, "orange");
  map.put(30, "banana");
  map.put(40, "watermelon");
  map.put(50, "dragonfruit");

  System.out.println("\n1. Export Map Key to List...");
  List<Integer> result = map.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(x -> x.getKey())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());         
  System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Have you looked in [Map docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)? You can use `Map#keySet` method, it returns a `Set`, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: There is no sense in using `.entrySet()` when your only interested in the keys in the first place. Just using `keySet()` right from the start saves you from the `.map(x -> x.getKey())` step altogether. On the other hand, you don’t need a stream operation at all. If you really need a `List` snapshot instead of the `keySet()` view, you can simply use `List<Integer> result=new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're calling here `map(x -> x.getKey())` is actually [Map.Entry.getKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey--)

So maybe try this

```
map(Map.Entry::getKey)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ask the `keySet()` of the map. It returns a set of the keys.

```
 Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put(10, "apple");
 map.put(20, "orange");
 map.put(30, "banana");
 map.put(40, "watermelon");
 map.put(50, "dragonfruit");

 System.out.println("\n1. Export Map Key to List...");
 Collection<Integer> result = map.keySet();         
 System.out.println(result);
```